# Update Column names from another table while exporting access table to sharepoint list

Tags: database, ms-access, sharepoint

I have an access database and i want to export some tables to sharepoint list.
The problem is that the table columns don't have actual names but numeric ids.
The actual names are stored in another table corresponding to those ids.

How can I update the column names while exporting this table to sharepoint list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a relation between the two tables and then export (upload) BOTH tables. You need the relationship since during an upload to SharePoint, the auto number ID are CHANGED. While you could up-load both tables separate, the existing data will be messed up due to the auto-number change.

If you upload both tables (with a relationship set), then auto number are updated and “changed” during the up-load, but the upload process is intelligent enough to “cascade” update the ID used in columns as FK’s (foreign keys) to that other list.

I explain step by step in this video how to up-load related data.

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL27E956A1537FE1C5&feature=plcp

Another possible solution if this is just a one-time upload would be to build a query that includes the text description, send that to a temp table (make table query), and then upload that table. However if this is a “active” or live linked Access database to SharePoint tables, then I strong suggest the approach outlined in the video link. If this is a one-time upload, then build a query that includes the text descriptons as a column and not the ID, and then as noted use that query as a make table query to create a temp table, and then upload that temp table. Which of the above two suggestions depends on if this is a one time up-load, or your goal is linked tables from Access.